# Asus Laptop Running hot with high fan speed after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: asus, 20.04, overheating, fan

Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  Running much hotter and fan running at high speed all the time. Even with no open programs. Cpu under 10%.
I did kernel 5.6.7 update. Still the same.

Asus ROG Strix Scar Edition GL703GE   - GL703GE.317

edit: updated to GL703GE.318

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.1Gi       4.9Gi       396Mi       8.5Gi        12Gi
Swap:         979Mi          0B       979Mi


coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +81.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +81.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +63.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           5.26 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +84.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h`. Do you have Nvidia? If so, what model, and what version driver?

Comment: Install `Vitals` GNOME Shell extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/ and tell me what your CPU temps are.

Comment: Boot to the latest 5.4.0 kernel, and purge the 5.6.7 kernel. Then `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`.

Comment: Latest BIOS is 318. Download at https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ROG-Strix-SCAR-Edition/HelpDesk_BIOS/. Latest Nvidia is 440.82 download at https://www.geforce.com/drivers.

Comment: Updated to GL703GE.318, better, but fan still running way more than with 18.04, even no applications running.

Comment: What does `Vitals` say the CPU temp is? What about the Nvidia?

Comment: Your machine is way too hot. It indicates that the CPU fan is not spinning at all... which may be incorrect? You may have more than one fan in the computer, since you hear the fan. I'd open the laptop, blow dust out of the fan(s) and general cleanup. The thermal paste on your CPUs may need refresh. Does the laptop still run hot if you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Heynnema, first should state that I'm running KDE.  I'm reluctant to open the laptop, it's less than a year old, not that it can't have those issues, but I be more suspect of hardware problems if the issue didn't start as soon as I updated to 20.04.

Comment: Well, just to check, did you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB as I suggested? What about the Nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was my Tresorit client service (cloud backup software).

Heynnema, thanks so much for the help.  I was able to narrow down the problem from your suggestions.  I installed the Simple Monitor widget (like vitals I guess).  This showed me that one of my CPU cores was running maxed at 100% constantly.  Using task manager I identified the Tresorit to be typically utilizing the most CPU.  After closing the task, my laptop returned to a normal temp of ~55C.